# Higher-ranked lifetime error on stable when converting AsyncRead to Stream

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await, rust-tokio

Here MRE: https://gist.github.com/legendiguess/776127783253c6e597be85bc122074f6

I get the following error:

```
error: higher-ranked lifetime error
  --> src/main.rs:27:28
   |
27 |       ) -> Result<(), Error> {
   |  ____________________________^
28 | |         let r = tokio_util::io::StreamReader::new(s);
29 | |         let d = do_stuff(&self.s, r).await.unwrap();
30 | |         Ok(())
31 | |     }
   | |_____^
   |
   = note: could not prove `Pin<Box<[async block@src/main.rs:27:28: 31:6]>>: CoerceUnsized<Pin<Box<(dyn futures::Future<Output = Result<(), std::io::Error>> + std::marker::Send + 'd)>>>`
```

Can someone explain this error and how to fix it?

I tried to add some more lifetimes, change `Impl Stream` to `Pin<Box<dyn Stream>>` but no success

Upd: it turns out that this successfully compiles on nightly, but on latest stable (1.70.0) it's still fails

Comment: The code must be embedded in the question, external links do not suffice.

Comment: Your code compiles for me (https://www.rustexplorer.com/b/1fpx5m).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman thanks for testing, it turns out - this code compiles on nightly, but on latest stable (1.70.0) it's still fails

Comment: This is probably a bug then. Check if it compiled on previous versions.